# How to draw a filled circle in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, graphics, geometry

I have a JPanel with a Grid Layout. In the "cells" of the grid I can put different elements (for example JButtons). There is no problems with that. But now I want to put a filled circle in some of the cells. I also would like to relate an ActionListener with these circles. In more details, if I click the circle it disappears from the current cell and appears in another one. How can I do it in Java? I am using Swing.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
   // Assume x, y, and diameter are instance variables.
   Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, diameter, diameter);
   g2d.fill(circle);
   ...
}
```

Here are some docs about paintComponent ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics))).

You should override that method in your JPanel and do something similar to the code snippet above.

In your ActionListener you should specify `x, y, diameter` and call `repaint()`.

Comment: Heh, thought it was a self-answer for a second there.

Comment: @mmyers: yes, it's a bit confusing))

Comment: @Roman Link is now dead.  [Is this a suitable replacement?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)

Answer (score 18):

```
/***Your Code***/
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
/***Your Code***/
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(50,50,20,20);
}

g.fillOval(x-axis,y-axis,width,height);
```