# Does all graphical objects have to inherit from JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem about Java Swing and JPanel. I could say that I am an unexperienced Java programmer, but not entirely new to programming.

My problem is that I have an class called `RandomParticle`,

```
public class RandomParticle extends Ellipse2D.Double {

    private Ellipse2D.Double circle;

    public RandomParticle(double xPos , double yPos,double rad) {
        setCircle(new Ellipse2D.Double(xPos, yPos, rad, rad));
    }

    public Ellipse2D.Double getCircle() {
        return circle;
    }

    public void setCircle(Ellipse2D.Double circle) {
        this.circle = circle;
    }
}
```

which I want to move on the screen (in a JFrame of course). The particle is a default object just to get up the graphics. However, it is said on many places, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509561/how-to-draw-a-filled-circle-in-java), that to be able to draw the circle it has to override the method `paintComponent` in the JPanel. It does indeed feel reasonable that, to draw something in a JFrame it has to be a JPanel. However this may cause trouble since Java does not support multiple inheritance.

In this case I do not really need `RandomParticle` to be a child of ellipse2D, but as my classes gets more complicated I will most likely need to inherent from some other class at some point. However, I felt this level of the question has a good dept for SO, since it does not require any specific knowledge of my program. So what I wonder is: **Is it possible to draw a circle without the class being a child to JPanel?**

Comment: MadProgrammer's answer explains Swing pretty well, but the answer to your question, " Is it possible to draw a circle without the class being a child to JPanel?" is yes.  Create a Circle model class, and create a Swing DrawingPanel from a JPanel to draw the Circle model class in the paintComponent method.  You can create several model classes and draw all of them in the order you desire in your drawing panel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible to draw a circle without the class being a child to JPanel?

Kind of, but it's wrought with issues.  I'll try and explain

If you want to perform custom painting in Swing, you should override the `paintComponent` method of any component which extends from `JComponent`, `JPanel` generally be the easiest solution, this is how painting works

Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works.

Generally speaking it's unadvisable to try and paint directly to a top level container like `JFrame` as it contains a number of other child components which are painted on top it (the `JRootPane`, `contentPane`, `glassPane`, `menuBar`, etc), which could be painted independently of the frame cause some weird painting artifacts.

A more detailed view of what a `JFrame` actually looks like...

[image: RootPane]

`JFrame` is also not double buffered, meaning that if you did try and paint directly to it, trying to update it quickly, it would cause flickering.  `JComponent` and it's decedents are double buffered by default

Swing itself uses a passive rendering engine, this means that you don't actually control the painting process, you are simply notified when your component needs to be painted (via the `paintComponent` method).  Swing may choose to paint child components without needing to notify the parent container, which is one of the reasons why `paintComponent` is generally encouraged.  It may also consolidate multiple paint requests in as few calls as possible, to optimise the process.

All of this is done without your knowledge or control.

If, however, you want more control over the paint process, you could consider using a [BufferStrategy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html), which gives you direct (double buffered) control of the painting process, so you can decide when and what should be painted.  But even this would require you to use a `java.awt.Canvas` as a base from which to generate your output.

As a general rule of thumb, it's generally discouraged to extend from `JFrame` (or most top level containers) and instead use one of the container classes as your base class.  This way you gain much more freedom over how they should be displayed or re-used, adding them to what ever other container you wish

Comment: Ok, I do now understand why it is good to use a `JPanel`. So what you mean is then that I should rather try to disconnect my other classes from its graphical implementation? Like for example letting all classes have a field `JPanel`, which can be drawn?

Comment: It's hard to know based on your code example, but it would be more likely that you would have a single `JPanel`/surface onto which all you other elements would be painted (they shouldn't know about the panel itself).  FYI `Graphics2D` (an instance of which is passed to `paintComponent`) can paint `Ellipse2D` using `Graphics2D#draw` or `Graphics2D#fill`.  Right now, all `RandomParticle` is a concept of a shape, it can't render itself. Have a look at [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: Thanks, that was instructive. What I mean is that I may want a class `public MyClass extends ComplicatedAndLongClass {...`. The representation may for example be a yellow circle. However, regarding your comment and some common sence I suspect this is not trivial and that I need to figure out how to best fit this into the design of my program. Thank you for a good and instructive answer. I now know much more about some swing components and the links was useful.

Comment: Glad it could help ;)